# Image in dialogbox from RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, dialog, imageview

Please need help with what's probably a small thing. I have a DailogBox which opens. Works and also the close button, but I can't seem to populate my ImageView with the image from my Arraylist in my onBindViewHolder.

Here is what I've done so far:

```
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewTwoHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.tvBrand.setText((CharSequence) modelTwoArrayList.get(position).getBrand());
    holder.tvImage.setImageResource(Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(modelTwoArrayList.get(position).getImage())));
    holder.tvImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View view) {
        myDialog = new Dialog(ctx);
        myDialog.setContentView(R.layout.details_activity);

        holder.tvImage=(ImageView)myDialog.findViewById(R.id.beer_logo);
        finishbtn=(Button)myDialog.findViewById(R.id.btnfinish);
        finishbtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                myDialog.cancel();
            }
        });
        myDialog.show();
        }
    });
```

Thank you for your time...and patience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image in your dialog is not `holder.tvImage`  
so change the below line:

```
holder.tvImage=(ImageView)myDialog.findViewById(R.id.beer_logo);
```

to `ImageView dialogImage = (ImageView)myDialog.findViewById(R.id.beer_logo);`  
and then

```
dialogImage.setImageResource(Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(modelTwoArrayList.get(position).getImage())));
```